# How to override popToRootViewController to append a method?

Tags: ios, swift

I subclassed `UINavigationController` and through its `didShow` delegate, which is called whenever a new view controller is pushed onto the stack, I update an instance variable called `previousViewController` (to be able to perform some custom work).

**The instance variable:**

```
class SectionNavigationController: UINavigationController {

    var previousViewController: UIViewController?
    ...
```

**The delegate where it is updated:**

```
// nav controller delegate method (did show)
func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, didShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {

    if currentIndex! > 0 {
        previousViewController = navigationController.viewControllers[currentIndex! - 1]
    }

}
```

As a consequence, however, whenever `popToRootViewController` is called, the view controller underneath the top view controller (`previousViewController`) is not deinitialized because of this reference. How can I override `popToRootViewController` in such a way that all it does is *append* the deinitialization of `previousViewController`?

Comment: try to declare it `weak var`

Comment: The notion of subclassing UINavigationController is a Bad Smell.

Comment: If an app has multiple navigation controllers and you want them all to look and perform the same way, why not subclass UINavigationController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html) apple documentation

> You resolve strong reference cycles by defining some of the
> relationships between classes as weak or unowned references instead of
> as strong references.

you should declare your `var` as `weak`